# Is there a more simple way to check multiple variables in an if statement

Tags: java

I want to check t1, t2 and t3 to see if they in the range of 13 - 19. If at least one of the the three are then I want to return true, if none of them are I want to return false. This code works but I wanted to know if there was a more succinct way of writing it, something maybe like:

```
if (t1 || t2 || t3 >13 && <19) return true else return false?
```

Here's my current code.

```
public class NumberChecker {

    public static boolean hasNumber(int t1, int t2, int t3) {

        if (  (t1 >=13 && t1 <=19)   ||   (t2 >=13 && t2 <=19)   ||   (t3 >=13 
        && t3 <=19)  ) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

}
```

Cheers

Comment: `return IntStream.of(t1, t2, t3).anyMatch(t -> t >= 13 && t <= 19);`

Comment: @shmosel, nice. Just to note: if it's important, I think the original solution will be much more efficient. Also the original solution can be done with just `return`, without `if`.

Comment: As mentioned by @ReputationFarmer: whenever you have a statement of the form `if (expr) return true else return false;` it is equivalent to `return expr;`

Comment: @ReputationFarmer, even if it's more efficient, the readability of the comment is superior, IMHO. Plus, the repetition of magic values and, as you suggest, explicit use of return true/false is a bit ugly.

Comment: This might fit better on the Code Review SE site, since your code is already working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself writing `if (x) return true; else return false;`, realize that you can replace it with the shorter and equivalent `return x;`. It may seem weird at first, but boolean conditions can be returned directly. You don't need to check if they're true and then return true.

```
public static boolean hasNumber(int t1, int t2, int t3) {
    return (t1 >=13 && t1 <=19) || (t2 >=13 && t2 <=19) || (t3 >=13 && t3 <=19);
}
```

You might then choose to extract the common range check logic into a helper method. It makes the code a bit longer, but less redundant. Up to you if you like this version better; it's an aesthetic decision, really.

```
public static boolean hasNumber(int t1, int t2, int t3) {
    return isInRange(t1) || isInRange(t2) || isInRange(t3);
}

private static boolean isInRange(int t) {
    return t >= 13 && t <= 19;
}
```

Comment: Or how about `boolean isInRange(int... tn) { for (int t : tn) if (t >= 13 && t <= 19) return true; return false; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [stream](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams) and an anonymous [lambda function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/) to do the match in one line:

```
return IntStream.of(t1, t2, t3).anyMatch(t -> t >= 13 && t <= 19);
```

Or you could use [varargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/) to automatically build an array from the arguments:

```
public static boolean hasNumber(int... ts) {
    for (int t: ts) {
        if (t >= 13 && t <= 19) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

<sup>(answers courtesy of [@shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553851/shmosel))</sup>